# converting 2D perlin-noise into brick wall texture?

Tags: perlin-noise, orthogonal

I would like to know how to make straight textures using 2D noise, to make stone squares of irregular sizes all jointed together (same as pic1): If there is a mathematical way to quantize 2D noise into orthogonal straight noise or jointed stone squares, please tell me the trick! (for a graphics shader brick wall texture generator)

if it is a mathematical impossibility, please tell me why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps, there is created a random texture size with noise: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32954/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-1

Comment: it doesn't actually answer my question although it was a very interesting game to read about and I was thinking of making a similar procedural kit for others to use

Comment: That would be very cool.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using 2D noise, but sampling adjacent points as though it was 1D noise, getting a series of strips of values. Then break those values into discrete groups, and whenever you run into a difference in group number, there's your break between bricks. And you would always have breaks between each horizontal strips.

Answer (score 0):

To make a procedural 2d/3d similar to square stones, it would be easier to use a voronoi base, because it is already the concept of cells... if each cell has square borders it will make 2d/3d square cells.

voronoi compares the proximity of pixels to central points around it, it makes lines tangent to the points, as cell borders. i am not sure how to make them 90 degrees, but there must be a way.